Fetch failed - following Solana Bootcamp lesson 2
I’m following bootcamp lesson 2 to fetch the balance of a wallet. The code is as per their example
import { Connection, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";

const suppliedPublicKey = process.argv[2];
if (!suppliedPublicKey) {
  throw new Error("Provide a public key to check the balance of!");
}

const connection = new Connection("https://api.devnet.solana.com", "confirmed");

const publicKey = new PublicKey(suppliedPublicKey);

const balanceInLamports = await connection.getBalance(publicKey);

const balanceInSOL = balanceInLamports / LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;

console.log(
  `✅ Finished! The balance for the wallet at address ${publicKey} is ${balanceInSOL}!`
);

Works fine on devnet but my wallet public key returns zero sol ( I assume this is because it’s a live wallet ).
When I change to mainNet and use the public key I get a fetch error. No other information that I can see.
I don’t think it’s a firewall issue as I am using a raspberry Debian to play and my router doesn’t have any outgoing blocks.
Am I doing something dumb ? Is there a trick to accessing MainNet ?
It is happening on every public key I try.
Sorry for the lack of details as there aren’t any to post.
Tim.

Does this answer your question? `TypeError: fetch failed` while trying to use Connection in web3.js

If it works on devnet then it might be your endpoint configuration,
on your script
import { clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));

Otherwise, It might have something to do with undici so check out this answer https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/14285/1708

Thank you heaps. Yes that was the problem. The tutorial needs a refresh.
